# 3D graphics in Jupyter notebook (ipynb)

Tags: 3d-graphics, ipython, webgl, jupyter-notebook

I'm searching for most convenient way how to insert 3D graphics into ipython (Jupyter) notebook? I mean some simple 3D model of machines (space-crafts in my case) mostly composed of simple primitives e.g. like CAD

What I want:

- people who read the notebook can interactively rotate the model
- The model is either loaded from file, or directly generated from python (or other) source code
- The model can be easily composed from simple primitives (lines, cones, cylinders, sphere ... ) within the code
- something which does not need some non-standard and hard-to-install dependecies, so anybody can easily run the notebook on this computer

Possible solution I found up to now (and problems):

- [FreeCAD IPython integration](http://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=IPython_notebook_integration) (just proposal, does not seem to be finished)
- [three.js](https://threejs.org/) - but I have no experience with neither Javascript nor it's [integration into IPython](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/), so I would prefer some python solution

  - [seen.js](http://seenjs.io/) seems to be exactly what I want, but again it is javascript
- [Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/) - it is for data-visualization, rather than for visualization of 3D models
- [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) - a bit too low-level, and I'm not sure how well it runs in web browser and Jupyter - I did not found any example
- [POVray](http://www.povray.org/) - is not interactive, integration to IPython would be cumbersome (calling external render, and than loading resulting image)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org/) with [itkwidgets](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itkwidgets).

Check the following example.

```
import pyvista
from pyvista import examples
from itkwidgets import view
dataset = examples.load_uniform()
dataset
view(dataset, slicing_planes=True, ui_collapsed=True, shadow=False)
```

That gives you the following result.

[image]

Comment: OK, this seams very good for 3D data plots. But if I want to visualize something else - e.g. polygon mesh (something like https://p3d.in/ ) ?

Comment: @ProkopHapala It is straightforward since it uses VTK.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open a 3D model into your Jupyter model (in .obj format that you can export from FreeCad) you can use [obj2html](https://pypi.org/project/obj2html/) ([Jupyter Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eQfp.png)).

You can do a simply hello world in this way:

```
! pip install obj2html
! wget https://gitlab.com/nicolalandro/obj2html/-/raw/main/test/assets/model.obj
from obj2html import obj2html
from IPython.display import display, HTML

obj2html('model.obj', 'index.html')

display(HTML('index.html'))
```

But probably for your models you also set light and camera in this way:

```
camera={
  "fov": 45,
  "aspect": 2,
  "near": 0.1,
  "far": 100,
  "pos_x": 0,
  "pos_y": 10,
  "pos_z": 20,
  "orbit_x": 0,
  "orbit_y": 5,
  "orbit_z": 0,
},
light={
  "color": "0xFFFFFF",
  "intensity": 1,
  "pos_x": 0,
  "pos_y": 10,
  "pos_z": 0,
  "target_x": -5,
  "target_y": 0,
  "target_z": 0,
},
obj_options={
  "scale_x": 30,
  "scale_y": 30,
  "scale_z": 30,
}
obj2html('model.obj', 'index.html', camera, light, obj_options)
```

You can read more at [source code](https://gitlab.com/nicolalandro/obj2html) page (It use three.js) or in [this medium article](https://z-uo.medium.com/visualize-3d-model-in-jupyter-notebook-e5a9deca20c6).